# Loading images using ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new to Angular.js and I'm trying to use ng-repeat and ng-scope to load a list of names and images from a txt file. However; after loading from a txt file it appears as though it can't read the arrays afterwards. I'm not sure why it does this because from what I've researched, ng-scope can load from objects such as:

```
app.controller("gameLoadCtrl",function($scope) {
    $scope.games = [{
        name: "Habbo Hotel"
        icon: "someimage.jpg"
    }];
});
```

but won't load in the way I try to format my list of games, which I'm positive is still the exact same format.

### index.html

The following is just the html code with the ng-repeat.
Loading the images is currently absent because I'm still trying to get just the names to load.

```
    <div class="main-container container" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="gameLoadCtrl">
        <span class="game-card col-lg-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-6" ng-repeat="game in games">
        {{game.name}}</span>
    </div>
```

### gameloader.js

The following is what I believe seems to be causing the trouble, once the list is returned from loadGames(), $scope.games will update but it will show blank results.

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.controller("gameLoadCtrl",function($scope) {
    $scope.games = [loadGames()];
});

// Load games and icon dir from txt file
function loadGames() {
    $.get("files/gameslist.txt", function (data, status) {
        // Split at unique seperator
        var gamesWithPicsList = data.split("<(O_O)>");
        var games = [];
        for (i=0; i < gamesWithPicsList.length-1; i++) {
            // Split game name and icon dir at seperator
            var gameAndPic = gamesWithPicsList[i].split(",");
            var game = "";
            var pic = "";
            // Slice off line break for all games listed apart from first
            if (i>0) {
                game = gameAndPic[0].slice(2);
            } else {
                game = gameAndPic[0];
            }
            pic = gameAndPic[1];
            // Add new game object to array
            games.push({
                name: game,
                icon: pic
            });
        }
        return games;
    }, "text");
};
```

The problem is definitely in loadGames() and the way I seem to be pushing it into my games array, but I can't figure out why $scope won't accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will never be able to load the games the way you are defining it.

`loadGames()` in your case is an asynchronous method.

So you will have to define the `$.get` in the $scope.

And don't call the method `loadGames`.

So instead of doing:

```
$scope.games = [loadGames()];
```

do this:

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.controller("gameLoadCtrl",function($scope) {
    $scope.games = generateGamesList();
});

function generateGamesList() {
    var games=[];
    var fileUrl = "files/gameslist.txt";
    $.ajax({
        url: fileUrl,
        type: "get",
        dataType: "text",
        async: false,
        success: function (data) {
            // Split at unique seperator
            var gamesWithPicsList = data.split("<(O_O)>");
            for (i=0; i < gamesWithPicsList.length-1; i++) {
                // Split game name and icon dir at seperator
                var gameAndPic = gamesWithPicsList[i].split(",");
                var game = "";
                var pic = "";
                // Slice off line break for all games listed apart from first
                if (i>0) {
                    game = gameAndPic[0].slice(2);
                } else {
                    game = gameAndPic[0];
                }
                pic = gameAndPic[1];
                // Add new game object to array
                games.push({
                    name: game,
                    icon: pic
                });
            }
            alert(games);
        }
    });
    return games;
};
```

Comment: Although your solution was still asynchronous ($.get was my problem as it is asynchronous), it helped me understand more about the methods I was using and how to deal with asynchronous functions. I've since changed my code to become synchronous but I thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

You have a little problem of understanding how it works. You are using function like it is blocking function but it is a [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

You should use it like this:

```
app.controller("gameLoadCtrl",function($scope) {
    loadGames().then(function(games) {
        $scope.games = games;
    });
});
```

You should also return value from loadGames function:

```
function loadGames() {
    // returns [$q promise][2]
    return $.get("files/gameslist.txt", function (data, status) {
        // Split at unique seperator
        var gamesWithPicsList = data.split("<(O_O)>");
        var games = [];
        for (i=0; i < gamesWithPicsList.length-1; i++) {
            // Split game name and icon dir at seperator
            var gameAndPic = gamesWithPicsList[i].split(",");
            var game = "";
            var pic = "";
            // Slice off line break for all games listed apart from first
            if (i>0) {
                game = gameAndPic[0].slice(2);
            } else {
                game = gameAndPic[0];
            }
            pic = gameAndPic[1];
            // Add new game object to array
            games.push({
                name: game,
                icon: pic
            });
        }
        return games;
    }, "text");
};
```

Comment: The second option will never work. You are including an asynchronous method call.

Comment: But When You call loadGames() You are getiing returned $q promise from it. You can call `then` on this returned value and in callback assign returned value to scope. So it will work.

Comment: That's what happened after I tried Pritams solution, it's gotten me somewhere, I just need to figure out this strange error. Thank you Hakier as well, however it didn't end up helping as much.

Answer (score -1):

following statement causing to create a nested array.
$scope.games = [loadGames()];
please try to  do like this 
$scope.games = loadGames();

or try to set the $scope.games value in loadGames function itself rather then returning.it will make your life easy:)